# What does “invalid … object at offset …” upon including PDF graphics mean?

Tags: xetex, luatex, includegraphics

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{included_file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

to xelatex, we get an expected PDF output but

```
invalid 13 0 R object at offset 259693

invalid 13 0 R object at offset 259693
```

on the console (not in the log):

```
$ xelatex mwe
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./mwe.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
invalid 13 0 R object at offset 259693

invalid 13 0 R object at offset 259693
 [1] (./mwe.aux) )
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

Here is some data on the included pdf:

```
$ pdfinfo included_file.pdf 
Title:          D:uploadedFile0cc7c497eb35f2a11447e94640dc1f-1bd5194ff4bb7acp1a120c7k41f6fedp15rf1gg11j0m.pdf
Producer:       ImageMagick 6.6.1-7 2010-05-07 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org
CreationDate:   Wed Oct  7 17:37:59 2015 CEST
ModDate:        Wed Oct  7 17:37:59 2015 CEST
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      59.52 x 55.92 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      260480 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

Being under NDA, I, unfortunately, cannot provide the reader here with the included PDF itself. (It was generated internally by my colleagues, is not available online, and can no longer be easily regenerated.)

Running lualatex instead of xelatex spits out the same messages as warnings:

```
$ lualatex mwe
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./mwe.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
warning  (file included_file.pdf) (pdfe): invalid 13 0 R object at offset 25969
3
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}<./included_file.pdf
warning  (pdfe): invalid 13 0 R object at offset 259693
>] (./mwe.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:35,3:4,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:34,9:38
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 221730 bytes).
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

Running pdflatex instead of the UTF-8 engines gives no warning.  The resulting PDF files seem to be visually equal regardless of the engine.

What does this warning exactly tell us?  Should we be worried or try to repair the PDF anyhow (uncompress and hack)?

Comment: How should anyone be able to say something definite if you can't provide the pdf?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought you said that talking to me would be a waste of your valuable time. Still, I'll reply to your question “How should anyone be able to say something definite if you can't provide the pdf?“ because it's apparently not evident to you: At least the folks who programmed the printing of the error message “invalid … object at offset …” presumably knew what they meant by this. If they read here, they are also welcome to reply.

Comment: The included PDF is almost certainly faulty: have you checked it using a PDF validator?

Comment: the message is from the pplib library,  you find it in ppload.c.  The message means what it says: the library identified an invalid object while parsing the PDF, but like the TeX error "Undefined control sequence" it is a quite generic message and without looking at the concrete PDF it is not possible to say what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I would try running the included pdf through certain programs that can sometimes repair errors in pdfs. One such is mutool from [mupdf](http://mupdf.com/): `mutool clean input.pdf output.pdf`. You can also try ghostscript (probably already installed if you have LaTeX): `gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input.pdf` (Try also with `-dNEWPDF=false` if using a very recent version of ghostscript.) Finally if on a system supporting [poppler tools](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/), there's `pdftocairo -pdf input.pdf output.pdf`.

Comment: @frabjous `mutool clean` seems to do the job on at least the file from the OP.

Comment: @JosephWright Any particular PDF validator you have in mind, perhaps available on standard Linux distributions? http://pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx , e.g, says, “The document does conform to the PDF 1.3 standard.”